# Data base Connection not work (database in antoher server, discord.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I have a problem with the database connection with my discord bot. The error it gives me is as follows:

```
Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:470:15)
    at Parser.write (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:33:29)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Discord\Firewall\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Discord\Firewall\index.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',
  fatal: true
}
```

I searched the internet for a long time but couldn't find anything that could help me
Important things that might help you understand:

- The database is on another server
- I don't use port 3306 but 3307
- PhpMyAdmin Database, is hgosted on a sinology NAS
  here is the code that i use:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
var con = 
mysql.createConnection({
    host: '192.168.1.86',
    port: '3307',
    user: 'JAWS',
    password: 'Coccodrillone_05',
    database: 'JAWS'
});
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("Connect error connecting");
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Connect");
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you try setting the host to localhost?

Comment: And if that's your real info... Maybe you should change it.

Comment: no 1) the ip is not the real 2) the password is like a big crocodile and yes is not the real password. Then the 3307 dor is only ion lan open

Comment: Can you try setting the host to localhost? – 
Newbie...           
no because e.g.: the server on which the bot is hosted is .2 and the database on .50 are on two different servers